# Why does For...Next Loop break after 2 run?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, iteration, break

I'm having problem with my code in Excel 2016, VBA.

Please have a look at the Code:

```
Private Sub Add_ProjectName()

Dim i As Integer
Dim iRowName As Integer
Dim iColName As Integer
Dim rFind As Range
Dim iFind As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Integer

'Find last row in Master Sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
ws.Activate

lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

'Start adding project names per day
With ws
    For i = 6 To lRow

        Set rFind = .Range(.Cells(5, 14), .Cells(5, 378))           'Each cell in this range is a date ranging from Feb 1 to Dec 31
        rFind.NumberFormat = "mm-dd"                                'Change the Format of the Date Range from "dd" to "mm-dd"

        iFind = .Cells(i, 4).Value                                  'The Commencement date of the Project


        'Find the Column of the Date that is equal to the Commencement date of the Project on rFind
        iColName = rFind.Find(What:=Format(CDate(iFind), "mm-dd"), _
                                After:=.Range(.Cells(5, 14), .Cells(5, 14)), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=True).Column

        'Set the Row of the Commencement date of the Project
        iRowName = .Cells(i, 10).Row

        'Adding the Project Name
        .Cells(iRowName, iColName).Value = .Cells(i, 10).Value

        Set rFind = Nothing

    Next i

End With


'Change the format of the whole range back to showing the Date only
rFind.NumberFormat = "dd"   

End Sub
```

So, this runs well for the first two iterations. Then when the third iteration starts, what I get was "Run-time error '91' - Object variable or With block variable not set".

After debugging, the system said that it was caused by

```
iColName = rFind.Find(What:=Format(CDate(iFind), "mm-dd"), _
                                After:=.Range(.Cells(5, 14), .Cells(5, 14)), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=True).Column
```

I check this again and again and couldn't find the "With block not set" nor Unset object.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Thi An.

Comment: Which statement is triggering the error?

Comment: The part where I have to find the Column of the Date, iColName variable to be exact. I'll edit the question. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: That means the `Find` method did not find a match. Try `Debug.Print`ing the value you're looking for before the search.

Comment: I put `Debug.Print` before `iColName = ` and get 3 value, i.e. `0, 101, 104`; before I bumped into `Error '91'`.

Comment: `Debug.Print iFind`

Comment: Here are the three values I got from `Debug.Print iFind`: `42823, 42826, 42807`

Comment: So you want to match a date ignoring the year, is that it?

Comment: Yes, as long as it helps me find `iFind` in rFind. :).

Comment: Why dont you search the date as is? why only the ""mm-dd" which is comparing based only on the month and day?

Comment: I tried it initially. For some weird reasons, it doesn't work. Only work when it's in the aforementioned format.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you try to find a string (returned by `format`) in a range containing `dates`. I would try

```
iColName = rFind.Find(What:=iFind,
```

instead.

Comment: I tried that as well, even before this. But I couldn't get it to run and figured out that it didn't match the elements in rFind, as I formated rFind to `"mm-dd"`, hence the matching format I used in `rFind.NumberFormat = "mm-dd"` and `Format(CDate(iFind), "mm-dd")`.

Comment: @ThiAn changing `rFind.NumberFormat` wont change its value for the search.

Answer (score 0):

I tried again today and figured out the problem was with the parameter `LookIn:=`. I changed it from `LookIn:=xlValues` to `LookIn:=xlFormulas` and it worked!

I had to tweaked it a little by using another row (in this case Row(1)) and put all the dates back to "General" Format (e.g., 42736 for January 1, 2017).

I added a Error Handler in case rFind returns Nothing.

Thank you very much for all your help @iDevlop and @A.S.H

Here is the working code.

```
Private Sub Add_ProjectName()

Dim i As Integer
Dim iRowName As Integer
Dim iColName As Integer
Dim rFind As Range
Dim iFind As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Integer

'Find last row in Master Sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
ws.Activate

lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

'Start adding project names per day
With ws
    For i = 6 To lRow


        iFind = .Cells(i, 4).Value      'The Commencement date of the Project

        'This is 365 days in a year shown in "General" Format
        Set rFind = .Range(.Cells(1, 14), .Cells(1, 378)).Find(What:=iFind, _
                                                                    After:=.Cells(1, 13), _
                                                                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                                    MatchCase:=True)

        If rFind Is Nothing Then
            GoTo NextIteration
        Else
            iColName = rFind.Column         'Set the Column of the Commencement date of the Project
            iRowName = .Cells(i, 10).Row    'Set the Row of the Commencement date of the Project

            'Adding the Project Name
            .Cells(iRowName, iColName).Value = .Cells(i, 10).Value
        End If
NextIteration:
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Definitely @Ralph. I can't up vote now due to my reputation as you've pointed out. But I will in the future. Of course I cannot accept my own answer so... Thanks for letting me know.